# Adding computed data to query in Django

Tags: sql, database, django

I'd like to add distance between two entities, and do this from Lat,Lng. However as these are computed between current user and all users in table, I need to do this on the fly. I'm computing

```
for record in list:
        rcdlat = record.MyLat
        rcdlng = record.MyLng
        d = ConvertLatLngD(mylat, mylng, rcdlat, rcdlng)
        record.Distace = d

return render(request, 'list.html', {'list': list, 'loggedin': loggedin})
```

However Distance does not exist in the model. I've tried this, but I cannot get the Distance out using the following in the template:

```
{% for record in list %}
    <td>D{{ record.Distance }}
```

But I cannot seem to see anything. How should I best merge computed dynamic data and records from DB?

Comment: did you catch the typo in your for loop (record.Distace instead of record.Distance)?

Comment: yeah, @miraculixx is right. Your code should work, dynamic attributes for objects work in django templating

Comment: @miraculixx Yes I did! That's cool! I can do dynamic fields!! Thanks